# Using regular expression to extract substring

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I want to extract  from `<` to the next  from my log-files.

```
$>cat messages.log
2013-03-24 19:32:37.231 <F280 [192.168.178.22]:5000 -- Unknown>, Msg:[Test1]
2013-03-24 19:32:37.547 <F281 [192.168.178.22]:5000 -- Unknown>, Msg:[Test2
Test3
Test4]
2013-03-24 19:32:38.833 <F280 [192.168.178.22]:5000 -- Unknown>, Msg:[Test5]
2013-03-24 19:32:42.222 <F281 [192.168.178.22]:5000 -- Unknown>, Msg:[Test6]
$>sed 's/.*\<\(.*\) \[.*/\1|/g' messages.log
F280|
F281|
Test3
Test4]
F280|
F281|
```

I almost got what I wanted except for the output with the newlines. So I'd like to have the following result:

```
F280|F281|F280|F281
```

How has the regular expression look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't create a unreadable regexp to do this I'd use `awk` here:

```
$ awk -F'[< ]' '/^[0-9]+/{s?s=s"|"$4:s=s$4}END{print s}' file
F280|F281|F280|F281
```

Comment: Thanks so far, it improved the output considerably better, but there are some more unwanted values printed if I apply this to my entire log-file. I'm not so familiar with awk, but may be you have an idea how to solve this message: "Msg:[Test5\n
AAA / BBB CCC DDD\n
EEE FFF]" => This leads to the output of "CCC" somehow!

Comment: So what can you filter by? What is unique to lines you want? How about if they start with `2013` `awk -F'[< ]' '/^2013/{s?s=s"|"$4:s=s$4}END{print s}' file` is that enough?

Comment: Yes, that did it, but I changed "2013" to "[0-9]+"! Why doesn't "[0-9]{4}" work with awk?

Comment: Awk does support the use of `{n,m}` read the regular expression section section in `man awk`. Something else must have cause no matches.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed -n '/</{s/^.*<\([^ ]\+\) .*$/\1|/g;H;${x;s/\n//g;s/|$//;p}}' messages.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that (you'll have nested groups), or turn on multiline option in regex:

```
(^.+<(\w+) .+$)+
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it compulsory to only use grep or are also other commands available?
I'd say that

```
grep "<.* " messages.log | sed  's/.*\<\(.*\) \[.*/\1|/g' | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/.$//'
```

The first grep is to remove data not following your desired pattern, followed by your sed command.
On the output, who should look like

```
F280|
F281|
F280|
F281|
```

The last tr command just removes the newline character at the end of each line (i.e it concatenates the result) while the last sed is just to remove the final pipe delimiter

Comment: This pipeline is overkill. A few tips however `grep -o "<[^ ]*" file` will filter the results much better, `sed` won't have to do quite so much work. If you have `GNU grep` then the use of positive look-behind gets you pretty much there `grep -Po "(?<=<)[^ ]*" file` then just some light work is needed to reformat `grep -Po "(?<=<)[^ ]*" file | tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/|$//'` but as my answer shows `awk` is a good tool for this.